# BeautifulSoup scrape itemprop="name" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some python 3.5 code that I want to scrape part of a web page with but instead of printing "Thick and Chewy Peanut Butter Chocolate Chip Bars" it prints "None". Do you know why? Thanks.

```
import requests, bs4
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

res = requests.get("http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/article/traybake-recipes/thick-and-chewy-peanut-butter-chocolate-chip-bars/list-page-2.html")
res.raise_for_status()
recipeSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
type(recipeSoup)
instructions = recipeSoup.find("div", itemprop="name")
try:
    method = str.replace(instructions.get_text(strip=True),". ",".")
    method = str.replace(method, ". ", ".")
    method = (str.replace(method, ".",".\n"))
except AttributeError:
    print(instructions)
```

[Link to scraped page](http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/article/traybake-recipes/thick-and-chewy-peanut-butter-chocolate-chip-bars/list-page-2.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `instructions = recipeSoup.find("div", itemprop="name")` to `instructions = recipeSoup.find("span", itemprop="name")` to get the recipe title.

For the instructions you'll have to search for `li` tags with `itemprop=ingredients`.